# Nestjs pagination with mongoose

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Alguien ha implementado mongoose paginate v2 en algún proyecto de Nestjs?
Si alguien puede orientarme les agradecería.
Los ejemplos que veo son con node y he intentado implementar algo parecido en Nest pero cuando llamo a la función paginate esta no es reconocida.

Aqui mi Schema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document, SchemaTypes } from "mongoose";
import * as mongoosePaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';

@Schema()
export class Product extends Document {
   @Prop({ required: true })
   name: string

   @Prop({ required: true})
   price: number

   @Prop({ required:false, default: 'active'})
   status: string

   @Prop({ required:false, default: 0 })
   rank: number

   @Prop({ required: false})
   description: string

   @Prop({ required: false})
   imageURL: string

   @Prop({ required: true, type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId })
   category_id: string
 }
 const schema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Product);
 schema.plugin(mongoosePaginate);
 export const ProductSchema = schema;
```

Answer (score 2):

Les comparto como lo he usado, espero les sirva:

dependencies:

> "mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.18"

devDependencies:

> "@types/mongoose-paginate-v2": "^1.3.9"

En el modulo principal configuro mongoose de forma asincrona **app.module.ts**:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [MongoConfigModule],
      useExisting: MongoConfigService,
    }),    
  ],
  ...  
})
export class AppModule {   
  ...
}
```

Luego en tengo el modulo para mongo **mongo.module.ts**:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as Joi from '@hapi/joi';
import configuration from './mongo.config';
import { MongoConfigService } from './mongo.service';
import { ConfigModule } from '@nestjs/config';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
            expandVariables: true,
            load: [configuration],
            validationSchema: Joi.object({
                MONGODB_URI: Joi.string().required(),
                DB_NAME: Joi.string().optional(),
                DB_USER: Joi.string().optional().default(''),
                DB_PASS: Joi.string().optional().default('')
            })
        })
    ],
    providers: [MongoConfigService],
    exports: [MongoConfigService],
})
export class MongoConfigModule { }
```

Además tengo el servicio donde registro plugins para todos los esquemas **mongo.service.ts**:

```
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigType } from '@nestjs/config';
import { MongooseOptionsFactory, MongooseModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';
import { MongoConfiguration } from './enums/config.enum';
import * as mongoPaginate from 'mongoose-paginate-v2';
import * as mongoAgregatePaginate from 'mongoose-aggregate-paginate-v2';
import configuration from './mongo.config';

@Injectable()
export class MongoConfigService implements MongooseOptionsFactory  {

    constructor(
        @Inject(configuration.KEY)
        private mongoConfig: ConfigType<typeof configuration>,
        ) { }

    get(key: string) {
        return this.mongoConfig[key];
    }

    createMongooseOptions(): MongooseModuleOptions {
        mongoose.plugin(mongoPaginate);
        mongoose.plugin(mongoAgregatePaginate);

        return {
            uri: this.get(MongoConfiguration.MONGO_URI),
            dbName : this.get(MongoConfiguration.DB_NAME),
            user : this.get(MongoConfiguration.DB_USER),
            pass: this.get(MongoConfiguration.DB_PASS),
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true
          };
      }
}
```

Luego tengo un controlador que llama a un servicio que entrega un resultado paginado:

```
import { BadRequestException, Inject, Injectable, Logger, LoggerService, NotFoundException } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { PaginateModel } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(
        @Inject(Logger) private readonly logger: LoggerService,
        @InjectModel(MyModel.name) private myEntityModel: PaginateModel<MyModel>,
        ) { }

        ...

    async search(filters: SearchFilterDto, pagination: PaginationDto): Promise<MyModel[]> {
        this.logger.debug(`search documents by filters`, MyService.name);

        const query: any = {
            mes: filters.mes,
            anio: filters.anio
        };

        const paginateOptions = {
            ...pagination,
            sort: {
                nombre: 1
            },
            projection: {
                _id: 0,
                __v: 0
            }
        };

        const results: any = await this.myEntityModel.paginate(query, paginateOptions);
        if (!results || results.docs.length === 0) {
            throw new NoContentException();
        }

        return results;
    }
    ...
}
```

Finalmente el esquema:

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Document } from 'mongoose';

@Schema({ collection: 'myCollection' })
export class MyModel extends Document {

    @Prop({ default: Date.now() })
    updateAt: Date;

    @Prop()
    nombre: string;
    ...
}

export const MyModelSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(MyModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo estuve buscando implementar el mismo plugin y no logré implementarlo. Me dí cuenta que no se puede implementar ya que NestJS tiene conflictos con los @types/mongoose, porque NestJS tiene sus propios @types para mongoose y chocan. Te recomiendo útilizar este plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-paginate.

Es algo desactualizado pero si no quieres hacer tu propio plugin/función para el paginado te puede servir.

Comment: Hola. Ya pude hacerlo funcionar. Si es de tu interés contactame y te dejo algún ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: Cómo lograste resolverlo?, no sé por donde contactarte.

Comment: Incluí una respuesta con la forma en que uso el plugin.